# Turning a multidimensional PHP Array into two different arrays

Tags: php

What I have is:

```
$choices = [
    ['horror' => ["Rosemary's Baby","Cujo","Children Of The Corn", "Congo"]],
    ['romance' => ["Sleepless In Seattle", "You've Got Mail", "Crazy Rich Asians", "The Notebook"]],
    ['sci_fi' => ["Alien", "Star Trek", "Star Wars", "Space Invaders"]]
];
```

What I would like to end up with is two arrays:

```
$genres = ['horror', 'romance', 'sci_fi'];

$collections = [
    ["Rosemary's Baby", "Sleepless In Seattle", "Alien"],
    ["Cujo", "You've Got Mail", "Star Trek"],
    ["Children Of The Corn", "Crazy Rich Asians", "Star Wars"],
    ["Congo", "The Notebook", "Space Invaders"]
];
```

I've been playing around with this for a couple of hours. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Since this is a pretty custom way of rearanging the elements to create new information, you have to create a custom method. There is no build in method to do this in a single step. Using simple for loops and basic array functions should be no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there is only one genre per choice the following works

```
$genres = $collections = [];
foreach ($choices as $choice) {
    $genres[] = $genre = array_key_first($choice);
    foreach ($choice[$genre] as $i => $title) {
        $collections[$i][] = $title;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you need to iterate the genres aswell

```
$choices = [
    [
        'horror' => ["Rosemary's Baby","Cujo","Children Of The Corn", "Congo"],
        'romance' => ["Sleepless In Seattle", "You've Got Mail", "Crazy Rich Asians", "The Notebook"]
    ],
    [
        'sci_fi' => ["Alien", "Star Trek", "Star Wars", "Space Invaders"]
    ]
];

$genres = $collections = [];
foreach ($choices as $choice) {
    foreach ($choice as $genre => $collection) {
        $genres[] = $genre;
        foreach ($collection as $i => $title) {
            $collections[$i][] = $title;
        }
    }
}
```